# Automapper ProjectTo is not mapping JsonB ColumnType of POCO Object

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, automapper, jsonb

I am using EF Core 6 with the Npgsql Entity Framework Core Provider. I have a table with a column type of jsonb mapped to a POCO object. If I query the database and use Automapper to `ProjectTo`, the property is empty. If I use Automapper to `Map` the object is populated properly.

The jsonb column is a list of POCO objects and I'm mapping to a `RepeatedField`, list of objects of same type.

Here is a working DotNetFiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlrnIQ

Comment: Try making the source `RepeatedField` and add a setter for the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the property you're looking to be populated by AutoMapper doesn't have a setter:

```
public pbc::RepeatedField<global::ProtocolBuffers.Protos.Configuration.Api.OptionsDefinitionModel> OptionDefinitions
{
    get { return optionDefinitions_; }
}
```

Comment: In version 10, all properties should be mapped even if there is no setter:  https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: That only applies to `Map`. How would you do it in a LINQ statement, without AM?

Comment: Thank you @LucianBargaoanu.  Is there any options as protobuf doesn't expose a setter?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html